# Animate elements in and out of page

Tags: javascript, html

I have several images that I need to horizontally cross the page to the right, exit the page and then re-enter the page from the left. Some of the images will already be out of view, so they will have to enter first.

This is a sketch of what I've tried so far:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

for (const elem of elems) {
        elem.animate(
          [
            // keyframes
            {transform: "translateX(300px)"},
          ],
          {
            // timing options
            duration: 5000,
            iterations: Infinity
          },
        );
      }
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 20px 0;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

For start I tried to slide out all the divs, but even that I don't understand why is not working.

Comment: It is not working because you are moving from point `0px` to point `300px` but your container and items are much more than that. Using absolute units such as pixel can make things much more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using your code as a starting point however there are 2 major differences between my code and yours. The first is that this solution is not using JavaScript, which is a plus, but it may not be what you are looking for. The second difference is that rather of animating the `div` elements with the class `child`, this solution is animating a wrapper `div` with the class `slider`.

One important thing to note, is that some calculations must be used for the animation to work properly. Adding or removing elements will require that the values are updated. The formula is the following:

- Child div size: 20% (CHILD_SIZE)
- Gap between children divs: 10px (GAP)
- Amount of the children: 8 (CHILDREN_AMOUNT)

So together it goes like this: `translateX(calc((CHILD_SIZE - GAP) * CHILDREN_AMOUNT));`

```js
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0];
slider.innerHTML += slider.innerHTML;
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px 0;
  gap: 10px;
  animation: slideRight 10s infinite linear;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(calc((-20% - 10px) * 8));
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateX(100% + 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated considering the comment:**

There are a few ways, the simpler way though is just to duplicate the `div.child` elements without touching the animation formula. This can be done just in the markup or using JavaScript to have a more dynamic solution (I have updated the code above to have the desired result).

What I consider a better way, though (not going to elaborate here as many libraries already solve this problem, just search for carousel js libraries), is to just prepend and append the necessary amount of elements to have the desired result instead of duplicating all of them.

Comment: Is there a way for no 8 to be right behind no 1 (so there is no waiting time until the red blocks appear again)?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is possible, but I added some JS to get the simplest solution.